# Set index check disable and enable on postgres database

Tags: postgresql, indexing, pg-dump, pg-restore

I want to set index check to 0 (disable) before restoring postgres pg_dump

`psql mydatabase;`

`SET_INDEX_CHECK = 0;`

--Run my database restoration

`SET_INDEX_CHECK = 1;`

Comment: The script generated by `pg_dump` will create all indexes after loading the data, so I don't understand your question

Comment: Similar to SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; then perform db queries; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

Comment: Again: if the script was generated using `pg_dump` there is nothing you need to do. The generated script will take care of everything (also: there is no `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` in Postgres)

Comment: My aim is to restore data without checking any contraint or indexes.